# JMeter 4.0: Error starting remote server

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to start a test on a Linux slave from a Windows master and get a FileNotFoundException for the rmi_keystore.jks file.

Windows master log file:

```
2018-05-01 09:13:56,336 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:13:57,487 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines
2018-05-01 09:13:57,492 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Tue May 01 09:13:57 CEST 2018 (1525158837487)
2018-05-01 09:13:57,492 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2018-05-01 09:13:57,495 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' is not defined, using localHost address
2018-05-01 09:13:57,495 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=XXX.XXX.XXX.38
2018-05-01 09:13:57,498 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2018-05-01 09:13:57,505 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=masterhostname/XXX.XXX.XXX.38,localport=49957]]
2018-05-01 09:13:57,508 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' is not defined, using localHost address
2018-05-01 09:13:57,508 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=XXX.XXX.XXX.38
2018-05-01 09:13:57,511 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=masterhostname/XXX.XXX.XXX.38,localport=49958]]
2018-05-01 09:13:57,542 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: XXX.XXX.XXX.37; nested exception is: 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\myuser\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
2018-05-01 09:13:57,544 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper
2018-05-01 09:14:20,343 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

I have created the rmi_keystore.jks file on the master using the create-rmi-keystore.bat script and copied it to apache-jmeter-4.0/bin on the slaves.

After having done so, when trying to start jmeter-server on the slaves, I would get a FileNotFoundException here also (see log and stacktrace below under "Linux slave jmeter-server.log 1").

Setting the property "server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file" to "/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/rmi_keystore.jks" however fixed this issue so that the slaves now start up with the following prompt output:

```
[myuser@slave1 ~]$ apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/jmeter-server
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[XXX.XXX.XXX.37:48508,SSLRMIServerSocketFactory(host=slave1.mycompany.corp/XXX.XXX.XXX.37, keyStoreLocation=/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi),SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi)](local),objID:[-5f3a9dbc:1631a887fa1:-7fff, 3570375527221520605]]]
```

... and log info:

```
2018-05-01 09:30:50,609 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2018-05-01 09:30:50,639 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/user.properties
2018-05-01 09:30:50,639 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/system.properties
2018-05-01 09:30:50,640 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: server_port=1099
2018-05-01 09:30:50,645 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2018 The Apache Software Foundation
2018-05-01 09:30:50,645 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 4.0 r1823414
2018-05-01 09:30:50,645 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_172
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2018-05-01 09:30:50,646 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =8
2018-05-01 09:30:50,651 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2018-05-01 09:30:50,651 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2018-05-01 09:30:50,651 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0
2018-05-01 09:30:50,652 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/myuser
2018-05-01 09:30:50,652 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/home/myuser
2018-05-01 09:30:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.37 Name: slave1.mycompany.corp FullName: XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:30:50,667 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' is not defined, using localHost address
2018-05-01 09:30:50,667 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:30:50,878 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=slave1.mycompany.corp/XXX.XXX.XXX.37,localport=52906]]
2018-05-01 09:30:50,885 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Starting backing engine on 1099
2018-05-01 09:30:50,885 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' is not defined, using localHost address
2018-05-01 09:30:50,886 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:30:50,886 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: IP address is a site-local address; this may cause problems with remote access.
        Can be overridden by defining the system property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' - see jmeter-server script file
2018-05-01 09:30:50,886 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating RMI registry (server.rmi.create=true)
2018-05-01 09:30:50,886 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' is not defined, using localHost address
2018-05-01 09:30:50,886 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:30:50,889 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=slave1.mycompany.corp/XXX.XXX.XXX.37,localport=1099]]
2018-05-01 09:30:50,890 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Bound to RMI registry on port 1099
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong with the setup? Is there a problem with controlling Linux slaves from a Windows master (notice the backslashes in the FileNotFoundException in the master log)?

I should perhaps mention that I have set remote_hosts=XXX.XXX.XXX.36,XXX.XXX.XXX.37 in the master jmeter.properties file and with success have tried to create a telnet connection from the master to the slaves on port 1099.

Linux slave jmeter-server.log 1:

```
2018-05-01 09:24:14,970 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2018-05-01 09:24:15,000 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/user.properties
2018-05-01 09:24:15,000 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/system.properties
2018-05-01 09:24:15,001 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: server_port=1099
2018-05-01 09:24:15,006 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2018 The Apache Software Foundation
2018-05-01 09:24:15,006 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 4.0 r1823414
2018-05-01 09:24:15,006 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_172
2018-05-01 09:24:15,006 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2018-05-01 09:24:15,007 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2018-05-01 09:24:15,007 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2018-05-01 09:24:15,007 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
2018-05-01 09:24:15,007 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2018-05-01 09:24:15,007 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2018-05-01 09:24:15,007 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =8
2018-05-01 09:24:15,012 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2018-05-01 09:24:15,012 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2018-05-01 09:24:15,012 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/home/myuser/apache-jmeter-4.0
2018-05-01 09:24:15,012 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/myuser
2018-05-01 09:24:15,013 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/home/myuser
2018-05-01 09:24:15,014 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.37 Name: slave1.mycompany.corp FullName: XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:24:15,027 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' is not defined, using localHost address
2018-05-01 09:24:15,027 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=XXX.XXX.XXX.37
2018-05-01 09:24:15,041 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Giving up, as server failed with:
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:383) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:346) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:225) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.<init>(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.startServer(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:245) [ApacheJMeter.jar:4.0 r1823414]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.loadStore(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:148) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:100) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        ... 15 more
2018-05-01 09:24:15,046 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred:
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:383) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:346) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:225) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.<init>(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.startServer(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:245) [ApacheJMeter.jar:4.0 r1823414]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.loadStore(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:148) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:100) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to create the keystore prior to starting JMeter slaves using `create-rmi-keystore.sh` script which is located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. See [Setting up SSL](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) chapter of the [JMeter User Manual on Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) for more details.

If you want to revert JMeter to previous behaviour (as it used to be prior to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)) you can start JMeter master and slaves like:

```
jmeter -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

To make the change permanent add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

and restart JMeter to pick the change up. See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter for more information on tuning JMeter using various properties.

Comment: Thanks, @dmitri-t. As I wrote above, I created the keystore file using the bat script on the master and copied it to bin on the slaves prior to starting the server processes here. I'll try setting server.rmi.create=false and see how it goes.

Comment: These options are mutually exclusive. If you want to use secure traffic between slaves and master - you need to create the keystores. If you don't want them - disable this option.

Comment: Setting server.rmi.create=false did not help, but when I instead set server.rmi.ssl.disable=true it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing thin in jenkins with performance plugin, you will have to change in

/opt/jenkins/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.1.1/bin/user.properties